# Toggle between two divs (two buttons)

Tags: jquery, html, css

Basically I have an image that is a blueprint for a floorplan, now there are two version of this image, one is 2D and another is 3D. I need two switch between the two divs but with two buttons and one with an active state. e.g. 2D link (starts with 'active' class). 3D link which when you click on will get the active class and the 2d link will lose it. Then also this needs to toggle between the blueprints below the links e.g. the 2d floorplan blueprint and the 3d one.

Hope this makes sense! :) Any help much much appreciated

```
<div class="flr-wrap">
<ul>
<li><a class="2d switcher active">2D plan</a></li>
<li><a class="3d switcher">3D plan</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="flr-inner">
<div class="plans 2d-plan active">
<img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url') ?>/img/floorplan/base.png" alt="" title="" /> 
</div>
<div class="plans 3d-plan">
<img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url') ?>/img/floorplan/base.png" alt="" title="" /> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: -1 found 426 results with 'Toggle between two divs'

Comment: I actually tried looking, there is plenty on how to toggle between two divs, but couldn't find anything on toggling between two divs with two separate buttons with an active class aswell as toggle between the two divs. My jquery is very poor. If you find one please i would love to see it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a method that may be of interest for it's leet-ness:

Use a pair of radio buttons to determine which div to show. The CSS `:checked` psuedo-class can be used to check which one is checked.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a2Zv9/)

No JavaScript of any kind involved, just pure CSS magic!

Comment: Not quite what i was looking for, but its pretty cool, definitely saving this.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
    <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="floors active" id="twodfloor">
        <img src="some-image.jpg" alt="2d">
        <button class="switcher active" id="twod" data-target="twodfloor">
    </div>
    <div class="floors" id="threedfloor">
        <img src="some-other-image.jpg" alt="3d">
        <button class="switcher" id="twod" data-target="threedfloor">
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    .floors {position:absolute;display:none}
    .floors.active {dispay:block;}
</style>

<script>
    $('.switcher').on('click', function(e){
        $('.floors').toggleClass('active');
    })
</script>
```

edit: if you need, you can toggle the active class in the buttons too, (as long as you have an initian active state in the button class).

Also, because the two floor divs are absolute positioned, you will need to declare it's wrapper dinensions so that your layout wont overlap.

edit
following your html, here's what will work for your case:

```
<div class="flr-wrap">
<ul>
    <li><a class="2d switcher active">2D plan</a></li>
    <li><a class="3d switcher">3D plan</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="flr-inner">
    <div class="plans 2d-plan active">
        2d plan
    </div>
    <div class="plans 3d-plan">
        3d plan wow
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<style>
.switcher {padding:5px;background:grey}
.switcher.active {color:red}
.plans {display:none}
.plans.active {display:block}
</style>

<script>
$('a.switcher').on('click', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 if ( $(this).hasClass('active') ) {
    //nothing, or notify it's already active
    alert('i am already active');
    } else {
        $('.switcher, .plans').toggleClass('active');
    }
});
</script>
```

and a [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Kf6dD/)

Comment: Hey m8, thanks alot, i dont seem to get it to work, i edited above and added my code so you can see the layout! thanks so much for you reply and help :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use the Bootstrap Framework's "Carousel" Feature, which give not only an easy, but also a styled (and customizable) carousel, which you can edit the CSS/JS file with everything you want

see http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel for the carousel

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Check out his [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qNNm8/).

```
<img class="img2" src="http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/x/3d-blueprint-house-11344095.jpg">
<img class="img1" src="http://advancedblueprintservice.com/images/blueprint.gif">

<button>Change</button>
```

jquery:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $(".img1").fadeToggle();
});
```